# debian/rules:161: recipe for target 'config.status' failed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, compiling, debuild

I am trying to build a deb package for `collect-pw`. The upstream tar ball is: 
http://perfwatcher.free.fr/download/collectd/collectd-5.4.0.20150311.tar.gz

For building this package, I pulled the source package for `collectd` from ubuntu repo and modified the package name under `debian/control` and `debian/changelog`.

Now, when I run `pdebuild` (OR `debuild` for that sake), it fails with below error:

```
configure: exit 1
debian/rules:161: recipe for target 'config.status' failed
make: *** [config.status] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here. The error is a generic error.
If I run `./configure`, `make`, then build goes fine.

Here are relevant lines from `debian/rules`

```
160 config.status: configure
161         dh_testdir
162
163         # This is a work-around for #474087 (broken openipmi .pc files).
164         mkdir debian/pkgconfig
165         sed -re 's/^(Requires:.*) pthread(.*)$$/\1\2/' \
166                 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/OpenIPMIpthread.pc \
167                 > debian/pkgconfig/OpenIPMIpthread.pc
168
169         PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(CURDIR)/debian/pkgconfig:$$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" \
170         ./configure $(confflags) CPPFLAGS="$(CPPFLAGS)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)" \
171                 JAVAC="$(JAVAC)" JAR="$(JAR)" JAVA_CPPFLAGS="$(JAVA_CPPFLAGS)" \
172                 JAVA_LDFLAGS="$(JAVA_LDFLAGS)" \
173                 || ( status=$$?; cat config.log; exit $$status )
```

Can you help with any pointers on what could be going wrong here? OR Any suggestion to make it provide *detailed error* would be helpful because 
`configure: exit 1` does not give much insight to act upon.

BTW, I have `export DH_VERBOSE=1` enabled in `debian/rules`.

Comment: If you still have  the case, would you share the complete rules file.